# The start of a game in pygame, blitting images to the screen

Tags: python, object-oriented, pygame

The small bit of code below blits and image to the screen within a class. I call this 4 times to display the image 4 times, each image has a different y coordinate and doesn't need different x but when they are blitted they make the code MUCH slower. I know it is the blitting as well due to the fact that if i just draw rects instead, the program moves smoothly.

```
tableTex = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('./Sources/Table.png'), (270, 240))

    def display(self):
        if not self.occupied:
            screen.blit(tableTex, (self.x, self.y))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (127, 0, 0), self.rect, 0)
```

A link to the full code can be found [here](https://github.com/tomayling7/restaurant-game/) if needed.
I just want to know if there is any reason this is so slow and if there are any other methods I could use that are faster?

Thanks

Comment: You should add the definition of `tableTex` to the code, since it is actually quite relevant.

Comment: @Graipher My bad - Updated it now

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [beginners guide](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html), you should convert your image right after loading it. So instead of

```
tableTex = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('./Sources/Table.png'), (270, 240))
```

Do

```
tableTex = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('./Sources/Table.png').convert(), (270, 240))
```

As noted in the guide linked above, this can lead to a speed-up of about a factor 6. The reason is:

> The 'format' that convert() refers to isn't the file format (ie PNG,
>   JPEG, GIF), it's what's called the 'pixel format'. This refers to the
>   particular way that a surface records individual colors in a specific
>   pixel. If the surface format isn't the same as the display format, SDL [what pygame uses underneath]
>   will have to convert it on-the-fly for every blit -- a fairly
>   time-consuming process. Don't worry too much about the explanation;
>   just note that convert() is necessary if you want to get any kind of
>   speed out of your blits.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, however using convert adds some very strange deformities to my loaded images https://imgur.com/a/htautZi

Comment: @ThomasAyling: I don't see them. But I just changed my answer to call `convert` on the loaded image, not the scaled one. Does that change anything?

Comment: No, i still get the same problem https://imgur.com/a/80IPaj7 (New image)

Comment: @ThomasAyling: That does indeed look weird (comparing it to the original in the github). Maybe the picture contains transparency which is wrongly interpreted?

Comment: Possibly, it works properly without the convert in still so maybe there were some issues with compression, i'll try re-saving it from Photoshop

Comment: I've also just notices a few extra pixels to the right of the tables... I have no idea what could be causing this.